# How to remove all flash objects from html with regex , code needed at c#

Tags: c#, html, regex, flash

How to remove all flash objects from html with regex , code needed at c#

Regex will remove all html objects from html so there will be no flash based objects at results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont think Regular Expressions is your best choice for this task, you should use the HTML Agility Pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/